# Beginner: Refreshing a part of a site using AJAX

Tags: ajax, href

I want to refresh with ajax just a part of a site.I searched protorypjs and i found ajax.updater but i am having trobule making it work.
this is part of my page

```
<li id="Home"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Can anyone tell me how i can implement this : Ajax.Updater(container, url[, options]) ?
and make it work?
I linked prototype.js in the html.

Answer (score 1):

One solution to update content is by using

```
$('#refreshMe').innerHtml(_new_ajax_content_);
```

where element is i.e. a

```
<div id="refreshMe">
```

If you want more specific help, you should post more information/code from your project.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. i made it work

here is what i wanted to do :)

```
<li id="Servicii"><a href=# onclick="new Ajax.Updater('container', 'servicii.html',
```

{asynchronous:true});">Servicii